# One widget hijacking another during on change event in Web AppBuilder app

Tags: javascript, arcgis-web-appbuilder, loading, arcgis-custom-widget

I have 2 widgets: a Manage Folders widget and a Task Manager widget. They sit next to each other in the navbar of my Web AppBuilder version 1.2 app. There are several other widgets as well. If I launch Task Manager after any of the other widgets, there are no problems. However, if I launch the Manage Folders Widget, close it, and then open the Task Manager widget, I immediately notice that a dropdown is sized a little larger than normal. This dropdown controls what task items are displayed in a grid below it. Normally, if I select a new item from the dropdown, it triggers and on change event that loads the tasks for the new selection into the grid. Now however, when I select a new item from the dropdown, nothing happens; the items from the previous selection (or default) remain the same.In investigating this issue in Chrome DevTools, I noticed that when I make a change in the Task Managers dropdown, the on change event gets triggered but then it goes to the 'loadData' function in the widget.js file for the previously closed Manager Folders widget. Note: they both have a function called 'loadData'. How could this be?! What seems to be happening is that the "thisWidget" variable is still assigned to "ManageFolders" so that when I call:

```
dijit.byId('subprojectSelect').on('change', function (e) {
    thisWidget.loadData(e, proj_type_obj);
});
```

in TaskManager, it is going to the "loadData" function in ManageFolders. How can I kill the ManageFolder "thisWidget" and make sure that it is assigned to TaskManager instead?

Any suggestions (other than renaming one of the loadData functions? Why would this be happening? Could this be something set incorrectly in one of the .json files?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This problem was completely caused by `thisWidget.` Both widgets used `thisWidget` to call other functions, specifically `thisWidget.loadData()`. Basically, I resolved the issue by adding the following code to **both** of the widgets in the `onOpen()` function:

```
onOpen: function () {
    thisWidget = this;
    ...
}
```

This way, when the most recent widget is opened, it's `thisWidget` is the one thats active.

Comment: I'm glad you solved your problem, but you might want to consider posting non-GIS related questions on a different site, like stackoverflow. You'll probably get more help there.

Comment: This is actually code specific to ESRI's Web AppBuilder (Developer's Edition) that utilizes the Dojo toolkit to create widgets. I even put that in the title of the question. I'm afraid that if I posted this over there, they would say the same thing.